# extracting data from html click event

Tags: javascript, meteor

This code tries to extract the value stored in `{{this.result}}` of the attribute `value` of the html input element
`<input type="radio" value={{this.result}}>`

```js
Template.options.events({
  'click .twin-item': (event) => {
    let elem = event.target;
    console.log( elem.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="options">
  <div class="twin-group js-radioGroup" data-id={{_id}}>
    <ul class="upShift">
      {{#each values}}
        <li>
          <label class="twin-item">
            <input type="radio" value={{this.result}}>
            <span class="radio-label">{{this.label}}</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

But the browser console is printing 2 lines, the first undefined and the second is the value I want.

How can I just get one print out which is the correct value I want? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fred,

I believe the reason why is because of [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing).

**Try this:**

```
Template.options.events({
  'click .twin-item': (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    let elem = event.target;
    console.log( elem.value);
  }
});
```

All I added was this [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

For your application, you might not need the `event.preventDefault()` you might just need to use the `event.stopPropagation()` to keep things under control.

You might also **try targeting** the actual input instead of the label.